# Love2D accessing variables from within a function

Tags: function, lua, love2d

I am trying to make car.x increase by 1 every time the 's' key is pressed, not every frame it is held down. In other words I don't want the car to go flying out of view as soon as the key is pressed. I initialized 'car' as an empty table {} and then car.x as 2 inside my love.load() function.
My love.load, love.update, love.draw, and love.keypressed are by themselves, not inside one another.
The following is my love.keypressed() function, which is outside of love.update().

```
function love.keypressed(key)
    if (key == "s") then
        print(car.x)
        car.x = car.x + 1
        print(car.x)
    end
end
```

When I run it, the console says:

```
2
3
```

Each time I press the 's' key. It looks like it is re-initializing car.x. Why is it not increasing each time i press 's'?

Thanks

Comment: You should post your `love.load()`. Also, from the print log you're showing us, it looks like it isn't re-initializing like you said? Does it output `2` and then `3` even if you press it multiple times?

Comment: `love.keypressed` should not be a part of `love.update`

Comment: Gage Hendy Ya Boy Yes it outputs 2 and 3 over and over again even if I press it multiple times.

Comment: Siemkowski i tried putting love.keypressed outside of love.update, and I got the same results.

Comment: Post your `love.update` and `love.load`. The error is not in `love.keypressed`.

Comment: "i tried putting love.keypressed outside of love.update, and I got the same results." Although this might not be the root of *this* issue, you should never have `love.keypressed` in `love.update`. Just FYI.

Comment: Found the problem! I simply initialized car outside of love.load and it worked fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ninjakid14 I would do some more research on the three: `love.load`, `love.update`, and `love.draw` functions. It sounds like there is a higher-level issue - probably misplacing those functions.

Comment: @Ninjakid14 sounds like you put your `love.load` inside `love.update`. If this is the case, here is your mistake.